# Using Requests Parallel processing to pull 100k plus data

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, python-requests

I know there are multiple solutions out there.

I have data of around 100k records. I am using python requests to pull this data from the server. I have noticed this process is taking really long. Its been 1 hour now waiting for it to finish pulling data.

Here is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests
data = {
    'token': 'server_data_token',
    'content': 'record',
    'format': 'csv',
    'type': 'flat',
    'csvDelimiter': '',
    'rawOrLabel': 'raw',
    'rawOrLabelHeaders': 'raw',
    'exportCheckboxLabel': 'false',
    'exportSurveyFields': 'false',
    'exportDataAccessGroups': 'false',
    'returnFormat': 'json'
}
r = requests.post('server_url' + str(r.status_code))
print(r.text)
```

I am thinking using parallel processing to loop 1000 records every round will speed up this but I am unable to incooperate that into this code. Help on adding parallel processing to help me get this data abit faster.

Comment: How many requests total do you have to make? Don't tell me it'd be 100K requests (because if so, I'd question if you didn't have an easier way to get this data).

Comment: @–wkl

I can do a batch of 1000 records for each loop

Answer (score 0):

Assuming OP can control the start/end record number in a batch (though I don't see it in OP's existing code). You can do a `ThreadPool`.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def get_data(batch_start=i):
    ...

with ThreadPool() as pool:
    results = pool.map(get_data, range(0, 100000, 1000))
```

This will spin up as many threads as # of your CPU cores. Each thread will make the request and wait for the result. While a thread is waiting, other threads can start making requests.

Comment: Thank you Tim, does this mean, I add my above code as it is inside the get_data function? What is``` i ```representing

Comment: yes your above code would go into the `get_data` function. The input `i` is essentially the batch number or the record number. Depending on how you can specify which records you can grab in a batch, this may have to be modified.